# TTT(TicTacToe) C++

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I want to write a TicTacToe program with 2 players (I am doing an exercise from the `Jumping into C++`). The syntax below does not have any errors, but let's say i input 1 or 2, the program just exits without any errors or any results. Here is the code that i came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int board_pos;



int main()
{
cout << "Enter => 1 for X; 2 for O:" << endl;

enum TTT_Board{topLeft, topMid, topRight, middleLeft, middleMid, middleRight, botLeft, botMid, botRight};
cout << "-------" << endl;

cout << "|" << topLeft << "|" << topMid << "|" << topRight << "|" << endl; /* Top cells of the board */

cout << "-------" << endl;

cout << "|" << middleLeft << "|" << middleMid << "|" << middleRight << "|" << endl;

cout << "-------" << endl;

cout << "|" << botLeft << "|" << botMid << "|" << botRight << "|" << endl;

cout << "-------" << endl;

if (board_pos == 0){
    switch (board_pos) {
        case topLeft:
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;
        case topMid:
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;
        case topRight:
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;
        case middleLeft:
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;
        case middleMid:
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;
        case middleRight:
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;
        case botLeft:
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;
        case botMid:
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;
        case botRight:
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }

}
else if (board_pos == 1)
{
    switch (board_pos) {
        case topLeft:
            cout << "X" << endl;
            break;
        case topMid:
            cout << "X" << endl;
            break;
        case topRight:
            cout << "X" << endl;
            break;
        case middleLeft:
            cout << "X" << endl;
            break;
        case middleMid:
            cout << "X" << endl;
            break;
        case middleRight:
            cout << "X" << endl;
            break;
        case botLeft:
            cout << "X" << endl;
            break;
        case botMid:
            cout << "X" << endl;
            break;
        case botRight:
            cout << "X" << endl;
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
}
else if (board_pos == 2)
{
    switch (board_pos) {
        case topLeft:
            cout << "O" << endl;
            break;
        case topMid:
            cout << "O" << endl;
            break;
        case topRight:
            cout << "O" << endl;
            break;
        case middleLeft:
            cout << "O" << endl;
            break;
        case middleMid:
            cout << "O" << endl;
            break;
        case middleRight:
            cout << "O" << endl;
            break;
        case botLeft:
            cout << "O" << endl;
            break;
        case botMid:
            cout << "O" << endl;
            break;
        case botRight:
            cout << "O" << endl;
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
}
else {
    cout << "Please enter: 1 for X, 2 for O, and 0 if you want you skip the cell";

}
cin >> board_pos;


}
```

NOTE: The Program does compile!

Comment: `main();` eww! You shouldn't recursively call main, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: DoItAllInMainMan. Seriously though, why do you need to enter 1 or 2 for X or O, can you just enter X or O and skip 1 and 2 altogether?

Comment: Also why have a `switch` for `board_pos` if you already determine it inside the if? double checking the same thing won't do anything. Also as far as I can tell all the inputs (1, 2 and 0) that you allow will immediately quit your program after a single further input.

Comment: Too much code and not enough information about the problem.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl yes that was my fault, i don't remember why i put it there... ill fix it

Comment: @redFIVE yes i could do that, but i just wanted to represent them in numbers

Comment: Why, though? What is your rationale. You should have a reason for doing everything

Comment: since i am just starting to learn C++ as a language in general, and i wanted to see if it works i guess @redFIVE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are recursively calling `main()`.

The standard states :

3.6.1.3

> "The function main shall not be used within a program."

5.2.2.9

> "Recursive calls are permitted, except to the function named main"

And you are reading the user input after this recursive call to `main()`, which, if this call ever succeed, will let no chance to your user to enter anything.

A program that compiles is not necessarily in good program.

Answer (score 5):

You should extract all of your logic code to a separate function, and then do `cin` in a `while` loop in `main()`, exiting when the user enters a non-number.

You should not be recursively calling `main`.

Comment: yes that was my fault again, i do not remember why i put it there, but good call...